# Makefile: extract an env variable from a docker container and use it in another docker container

Tags: docker, makefile, environment-variables

I have an app that runs on several docker containers. To simplify my problem let's say I have 3 containers : one for MySQL and 2 for 2 instances of the api (sharing the same volume where the code is but with a different `env` specifying different database settings) as configured in the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  api-1:
    image: mynamespace/my-image-name:1.0
    environment:
      DB_NAME: db_api_1
  api-2:
    image: mynamespace/my-image-name:1.0
    environment:
      DB_NAME: db_api_2
```

In a `Makefile` I have rules for deploying the containers and installing the database for each of my api instances.

What I am trying to achieve is to create a `make` rule that dumps a database given an `env`. Knowing that I have no MySQL client installed on my api instances, I thought there should be a way to extract the `env` variables I need (with `printenv VARNAME`) from an api container then use it in the database container.

Anyone knows how this could be achieved ?

Comment: When you say 3 containers do you mean 3 separate docker images? Or is the MySQL container from one docker image and the 2 API instances are two containers created from the same docker image? How do you specify a different env variable for each of the 2 API instances?

Comment: it's 1 container from a MySQL image and 2 API from the same image but with different env. I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's an environment variable that you set using the `-e` option to `docker run`, you could do something like this:

```
docker exec api_container sh -c 'echo $VARNAME'
```

If it is environment variable that was set inside the container e.g. from a script, then you're mostly out of luck.  You could of course inspect `/proc/<pid>/environ`, but that's hacky and I wouldn't recommend it.

It also sounds as if you would benefit from using something like [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to manage your containers.

Comment: I am using `docker-compose` and your solution wont work in a Makefile as `'echo $VARNAME'` tries to read `$V` which is empty and ends up echoing `ARNAME`

Comment: You need to escape the `$` in your Makefile if you are trying to refer to shell variables.  `echo $$VARNAME`. See the [Make docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-reference-to-variables) for more information.

Comment: OK Great, thanks I didn't know that's how dollar signs were escaped. So now I've extracted the variable (I had already achieved that with `docker exec api_container printenv VARNAME`), is there a way I can use that variable in a subsequent command targetting the `database` container ?